# Select data from one table that coincides with another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How do I display the review for a film ?

This is my query  -

```
$query = "SELECT movies.movie_id, movies.movie_title, 
                    FROM movies
                    INNER JOIN reviews
                    ON reviews.review_id=reviews.fk_movie_review";




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `movie_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `actor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fk_movie_ratings` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--


INSERT INTO `movies` (`movie_id`, `movie_title`, `actor`, `fk_movie_ratings`) VALUES
(1, 'Batman Begins', 'Christian Bale', 5);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` (
  `rating_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `rating_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rating_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `ratings` (`rating_id`, `rating_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Excellent'),
(2, 'Brilliant'),
(3, 'Good'),
(4, 'Ok'),
(5, 'Terrible');



--
-- Table structure for table `reviews`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reviews` (
  `review_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_review` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `fk_movie_review` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;



INSERT INTO `reviews` (`review_id`, `movie_review`, `fk_movie_review`) VALUES
(1, 'Wicked', 1);
```

Comment: What's the actual question? How do I display the review for a film is not a question - we have no knowledge of the actual piece of the process you're struggling with.

Comment: This is a very simple `JOIN` question. Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT movies.movie_id, movies.movie_title, reviews.*
                    FROM movies
                    INNER JOIN reviews
                    ON movies.movie_id=reviews.fk_movie_review";
```

Join condition does not refer movies table?

And you also need more columns in select as Thomas Andrews spotted

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your join you have specified both columns in `ON` clause from `review` table you have not joined the movies table

```
SELECT movies.movie_id, movies.movie_title,reviews.movie_review
FROM movies
INNER JOIN reviews
ON movies.movie_id=reviews.fk_movie_review
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MOVIES.MOVIE_ID, 
       MOVIES.MOVIE_TITLE, 
       REVIEWS.MOVIE_REVIEW 
FROM   MOVIES 
       LEFT JOIN REVIEWS 
              ON REVIEWS.FK_MOVIE_REVIEW = MOVIES.MOVIE_ID
```

Comment: What's the problem here?


"SELECT movies.movie_id, movies.movie_title, reviews.movie_review 
FROM movies LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.fk_movie_review = movies.movie_id".

You just edited with all upper case,nothing else.